# express js route never hits /:id

Tags: javascript, express, routes, axios

I have a situation when I can not access a express js route which points to "/:id". It always hits "/" and I do not understand why?

The code in my controller is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

var Reservation = require('./Reservation');

// GET all reservations
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Reservation.find({}).populate('client').exec(function (err, reservation) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("Issues retrieving all reservations.");
        res.status(200).send(reservation);
    });
});

// GET only one reservation based on its ID
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    Reservation.findById(req.params.id).populate('client').exec(function (err, reservation) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("Issues finding the reservation.");
        if (!reservation) return res.status(404).send("Reservation not found.");
        res.status(200).send(reservation);
    });
});
```

In my `app.js` file, I mount the controller onto the route as follows:

```
var ReservationController = require('./reservations/ReservationController'); 
app.use('/api/reservations', ReservationController);
```

This is how I'm trying to retrieve the reservation by id using Axios:

```
axios
  .get('http://localhost:3000/api/reservations/', {
      params: {
        id: '5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8'
      }
  })
  .then(response => {
    // handle response
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // handle errors
  })
```

Tried using Postman with the same results, I'm always getting "/" instead of "/:id".

Answer (score 3):

`GET /api/reservations` doesn't match `/:id`. `/:id` implies that the route is called by passing the id as a path parameter.

You can invoke `/:id` by using :

```
axios.get('/5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8')
```

This matches `/:id`. And then you'll get `req.params.id=="5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8"` in your route handler function.

If you call `/api/reservations`, it would match router.get('/:param1/:param2') and then you'd get `req.params.param1=="api"` and `req.params.param2=="reservations"`.

**Edit** (by @ChiragRavindra)

If you intended to call `/api/reservations/5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8`, you would need need to change your matching expression to: `router.get('/api/reservations/:id', function (req, res) {...}`
(Assuming you are not mounting your controller on `/api/reservations` in the first place). You can then invoke it like:

`axios.get('/api/reservations/5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8')`

If you want to keep the invocation the same as you have posted in the question, you will have to change the HTTP method to `PUT` or `POST` from `GET`

```
router.post('/api/reservations', function (req, res) {
    //req.body.params.id === '5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8'
});



axios
.post('/api/reservations/', {
    params: {
        id: '5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8'
    }
})
.then(response => {
    // handle response
})
.catch(e => {
    // handle errors
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think your reply is accurate, because in my app.js I have:

    `var ReservationController = require('./reservations/ReservationController');
    app.use('/api/reservations', ReservationController);`

Comment: @AlexandruPopovici that was not clear in the question. In that case, try `axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/reservations/5a6dd589a90c1e83d3c3ebb8")`. The concept behind this answer still holds. Have put in some edits. Waiting for them to come through

Comment: @ChiragRavindra I have approved your addition to my answer, but not the parts that you have changed in what I had written. You had removed the :param1 and :param2 explanation, uh, no mate, I'd like to keep that thanks. Also, you had added `http://localhost:3000` to my URL, when I had explicitely removed it in the first place, so I kept my original text as well. The host's root is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @JeremyThille whatever works! Had typed out my own answer so I reused parts of that. Just to let you know what my thought process was: 1) I felt `/param1/param2` was superfluous information as it was never mentioned in the question. and 2) OP had `http://localhost:3000` in the code. I did not want to assume that the API host was the same as the application host

Comment: Fair enough. `superfluous information as it was never mentioned in the question` --> That's the extra teaching mile ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that you declared first '/' path than '/:id'.

So, the middleware try to match every entry request in the same order you declared the paths. The request you send with the id is probably being treated by the first method because it matchs the path. You always have to declare more specific paths first, and then the generic ones. Other case, specific ones are not going to work ever.

Change the order you delcared the paths into the middleware and tell me if it worked.